# How to pass variable to view without using url in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

guys. I'm a newbie of Laravel.

I'm just wondering that if I need to pass some sensitive info, which is been wrote on a form, to controller, then to another view.

How could I pass the info to the view without using URL?

I have made some small test, but the result is all the same (url would include the data).
Here is the code.

Html(a):

```
<form action="/data" method="GET" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Test">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">test</button>
</div>
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('/data', 'DataController@show');
```

DataController.php:

```
    public function show(Request $request) {
    return view('testShow');
}
```

Html(b):

```
<div class="ShowDataHere">
@if(!empty(request()->all()))
    {{ request()->Test }}
@endif
```

Comment: use POST instead of GET

Comment: But how? I add a route    `Route::post('/data', 'DataController@show');` and change the method GET from POST but the result would be the same. If I try to delete the line of Route::get one I'll get an error.

Comment: You can make use of sessions or simply save it to the database and query when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change your form to use POST instead of GET.

On the form...

```
<form action="/data" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
```

In your route ...

```
Route::post('/data', 'DataController@show');
```

This will send all of the form fields to the server in a way that is less visable (not in the URL) but to make the form secure, you'll want to ensure it's served using HTTPS as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel when you use Route::post('/data', 'DataController@show') the Laravel expect a GET, because of the show function.

So you can use Route::post('/data', 'DataController@someFunction') and in your laravel controller get with:

```
public function someFunction(Request $request)
    {
        $array = $request->all(); //your fields
    }
```

In this function you can get the attributes with $array = $request->all();